# Correcting for unwanted Roll when Rotating on all 3 axes locally

Tags: c++, 3d, rotation, transform, unreal-engine4

I am making a game in which you can move and rotate freely in all directions/axis. Due to how the 3d rotation calculations works, when changing pitch and yaw, a small roll is induced as well over time.

As I have found out, the only way to do this when applying rotation locally (delta rotation based on input each frame) is gradually compensating for it. How would I do this?

The result should be when I am strafing around an object, my relative up vector should stay the same, like I was moving on a 2D plane.

Thanks Jack

Comment: See [this question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738139/prevent-rotation-around-certain-axis-with-quaternion/46741647#46741647). The other question talks about quaternions, but the same applies to matrices.

Comment: Quaternions are alright for me. That answer doesn't seem to include roll as well, where would that fall into the equation? Cause the player can roll itself as well intentionally. Or does the actual roll input not matter and I need to just apply yaw before pitch?

Comment: After some testing this doesn't seem to help at all. Also I only do one pitch and yaw rotation per frame, so maybe it is describing a different problem? I know one solution to this issue is separating pitch and roll transforms, like rotating whole character as yaw and only head to pitch, however that does not work well when roll is induced as well.

Comment: I just realized that you actually want a rotation with three degrees of freedom. Could you describe in more details what kind of behavior you want? Do you want the yaw rotations about the world's up-vector instead of the camera's up-vector? How do you want this to behave with an already rolled camera?

Comment: Imagine strafing right and using yaw left to keep orbiting around the box. Your up vector should stay aligned with the box. When you roll 90 degrees to the right and again you start orbiting the box with strafing right and yaw left (relative to you) your up vector should stay aligned to the top of the box (which is now boxes vector right). I hope it makes sense. Basically I always want to move on a 2d plane relative to the player until I roll.